# How JWT actually works with Spring MVC to create token and validate token?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, jwt

I am actually looking to get more and clear understanding over the `JWT` concept and how it works with `Spring MVC`. I found link https://github.com/nielsutrecht/jwt-angular-spring, whose program works absolutely fine. **But I wonder how it creates token and then how user gets login into the application.** I need some clarification / answer how it works? Please do needful.

My understanding: It appears to me that when you launch the application, GenericFilterBean implementation class will be called which will generate the JWT token and send it to UI in local storage (not sure though) and then this token will come in header with request and then it will get validated and access will be given to user ?

I would like to put some code snippet for reference (even you can look for code from link mentioned)

AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter.java

```
public class AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private final UserDetailsService userService;

    public AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter(UserDetailsService userService){
        this.userService = userService;
    }


    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,ServletException{
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = this.getAsHttpRequest(request);

        String authToken = this.extractAuthTokenFromRequest(httpRequest);
        String userName = TokenUtils.getUserNameFromToken(authToken);

        if (userName != null) {

            UserDetails userDetails = this.userService.loadUserByUsername(userName);

            if (TokenUtils.validateToken(authToken, userDetails)) {

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpRequest));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }


    private HttpServletRequest getAsHttpRequest(ServletRequest request){
        if (!(request instanceof HttpServletRequest)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Expecting an HTTP request");
        }

        return (HttpServletRequest) request;
    }


    private String extractAuthTokenFromRequest(HttpServletRequest httpRequest){
        /* Get token from header */
        String authToken = httpRequest.getHeader("X-Auth-Token");
        System.out.println("AUTH TOKEN : "+authToken);

        /* If token not found get it from request parameter */
        if (authToken == null) {
            authToken = httpRequest.getParameter("token");
        }
        return authToken;
    }
}
```

TokenUtils.java

```
public class TokenUtils{
    public static final String MAGIC_KEY = "obfuscate";

    public static String createToken(UserDetails userDetails){
        System.out.println(" ----- Create Token ------");
        /* Expires in one hour */
        long expires = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000L * 60 * 60;

        StringBuilder tokenBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        tokenBuilder.append(userDetails.getUsername());
        tokenBuilder.append(":");
        tokenBuilder.append(expires);
        tokenBuilder.append(":");
        tokenBuilder.append(TokenUtils.computeSignature(userDetails, expires));

        return tokenBuilder.toString();
    }


    public static String computeSignature(UserDetails userDetails, long expires){
        System.out.println("------ Compute Signature ------");
        StringBuilder signatureBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        signatureBuilder.append(userDetails.getUsername());
        signatureBuilder.append(":");
        signatureBuilder.append(expires);
        signatureBuilder.append(":");
        signatureBuilder.append(userDetails.getPassword());
        signatureBuilder.append(":");
        signatureBuilder.append(TokenUtils.MAGIC_KEY);

        MessageDigest digest;
        try {
            digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No MD5 algorithm available!");
        }
        System.out.println(new String(Hex.encode(digest.digest(signatureBuilder.toString().getBytes()))));
        return new String(Hex.encode(digest.digest(signatureBuilder.toString().getBytes())));
    }


    public static String getUserNameFromToken(String authToken){
        System.out.println("----- Get Username From TOken ----");
        if (null == authToken) {
            return null;
        }

        String[] parts = authToken.split(":");
        return parts[0];
    }


    public static boolean validateToken(String authToken, UserDetails userDetails)  {
        System.out.println("=== Validate Token ===");
        String[] parts = authToken.split(":");
        long expires = Long.parseLong(parts[1]);
        String signature = parts[2];

        if (expires < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            return false;
        }
        System.out.println(signature.equals(TokenUtils.computeSignature(userDetails, expires)));
        return signature.equals(TokenUtils.computeSignature(userDetails, expires));
    }
}
```

Context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- MySQL DataSource -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.pass}" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Entity Manager Factory -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="examplePU" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="newsEntryDao" class="net.dontdrinkandroot.dao.newsentry.JpaNewsEntryDao" />

    <bean id="userDao" class="net.dontdrinkandroot.dao.user.JpaUserDao" />

    <bean id="dataBaseInitializer" class="net.dontdrinkandroot.dao.DataBaseInitializer" init-method="initDataBase">
        <constructor-arg ref="userDao" />
        <constructor-arg ref="newsEntryDao" />
        <constructor-arg ref="passwordEncoder" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- =======================
        INIT REST COMPONENTS 
         ======================= -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="net.dontdrinkandroot.resources" />

    <bean id="objectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper" />



    <!-- ====================================== 
        SPRING SECURITY SETUP
         ====================================== -->

    <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder">
        <constructor-arg value="ThisIsASecretSoChangeMe" />
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDao">
            <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"></security:password-encoder>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:http
            realm="Protected API"
            use-expressions="true"
            auto-config="false"
            create-session="stateless"
            entry-point-ref="unauthorizedEntryPoint"
            authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/user/authenticate" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url method="GET" pattern="/rest/news/**" access="hasRole('user')" />
        <security:intercept-url method="PUT" pattern="/rest/news/**" access="hasRole('admin')" />
        <security:intercept-url method="POST" pattern="/rest/news/**" access="hasRole('admin')" />
        <security:intercept-url method="DELETE" pattern="/rest/news/**" access="hasRole('admin')" />
    </security:http>

    <bean id="unauthorizedEntryPoint" class="net.dontdrinkandroot.rest.UnauthorizedEntryPoint" />

    <bean id="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter" class="net.dontdrinkandroot.rest.AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter" >
        <constructor-arg ref="userDao" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

EDIT-1:

```
AUTH TOKEN : null
----- Get Username From Token ----
Jan 01, 2016 2:35:01 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent filterFormParameters
WARNING: A servlet request, to the URI http://localhost:8080/angular-rest-security/rest/user/authenticate, contains form parameters in the request body but the request body has been consumed by the servlet or a servlet filter accessing the request parameters. Only resource methods using @FormParam will work as expected. Resource methods consuming the request body by other means will not work as expected.
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_1_, user0_.name as name2_1_, user0_.password as password3_1_ from User user0_ where user0_.name=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.User_id as User_id1_1_0_, roles0_.roles as roles2_2_0_ from User_roles roles0_ where roles0_.User_id=?
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_1_, user0_.name as name2_1_, user0_.password as password3_1_ from User user0_ where user0_.name=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.User_id as User_id1_1_0_, roles0_.roles as roles2_2_0_ from User_roles roles0_ where roles0_.User_id=?
 ----- Create Token ------
------ Compute Signature ------
525b8e635bb234684d2a02b99f38d687
AUTH TOKEN : null
----- Get Username From Token ----
Jan 01, 2016 2:36:27 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent filterFormParameters
WARNING: A servlet request, to the URI http://localhost:8080/angular-rest-security/rest/user/authenticate, contains form parameters in the request body but the request body has been consumed by the servlet or a servlet filter accessing the request parameters. Only resource methods using @FormParam will work as expected. Resource methods consuming the request body by other means will not work as expected.
AUTH TOKEN : admin:1451599569652:525b8e635bb234684d2a02b99f38d687
----- Get Username From Token ----
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_1_, user0_.name as name2_1_, user0_.password as password3_1_ from User user0_ where user0_.name=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.User_id as User_id1_1_0_, roles0_.roles as roles2_2_0_ from User_roles roles0_ where roles0_.User_id=?
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_1_, user0_.name as name2_1_, user0_.password as password3_1_ from User user0_ where user0_.name=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.User_id as User_id1_1_0_, roles0_.roles as roles2_2_0_ from User_roles roles0_ where roles0_.User_id=?
=== Validate Token ===
------ Compute Signature ------
525b8e635bb234684d2a02b99f38d687
true
------ Compute Signature ------
525b8e635bb234684d2a02b99f38d687
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_1_, user0_.name as name2_1_, user0_.password as password3_1_ from User user0_ where user0_.name=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.User_id as User_id1_1_0_, roles0_.roles as roles2_2_0_ from User_roles roles0_ where roles0_.User_id=?
 ----- Create Token ------
------ Compute Signature ------
b6238344022f3f4dd3787f0f8fa99b44
AUTH TOKEN : null
----- Get Username From Token ----
AUTH TOKEN : admin:1451599596826:b6238344022f3f4dd3787f0f8fa99b44
----- Get Username From Token ----
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_1_, user0_.name as name2_1_, user0_.password as password3_1_ from User user0_ where user0_.name=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.User_id as User_id1_1_0_, roles0_.roles as roles2_2_0_ from User_roles roles0_ where roles0_.User_id=?
=== Validate Token ===
------ Compute Signature ------
b6238344022f3f4dd3787f0f8fa99b44
true
------ Compute Signature ------
b6238344022f3f4dd3787f0f8fa99b44
AUTH TOKEN : admin:1451599596826:b6238344022f3f4dd3787f0f8fa99b44
----- Get Username From Token ----
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_1_, user0_.name as name2_1_, user0_.password as password3_1_ from User user0_ where user0_.name=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.User_id as User_id1_1_0_, roles0_.roles as roles2_2_0_ from User_roles roles0_ where roles0_.User_id=?
=== Validate Token ===
------ Compute Signature ------
b6238344022f3f4dd3787f0f8fa99b44
true
------ Compute Signature ------
b6238344022f3f4dd3787f0f8fa99b44
02:36:38,728 INFO NewsEntryResource.list():49 - list()
Hibernate: select newsentry0_.id as id1_0_, newsentry0_.content as content2_0_, newsentry0_.date as date3_0_ from NewsEntry newsentry0_ order by newsentry0_.date desc
AUTH TOKEN : null
----- Get Username From Token ----
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm the author of the link (https://github.com/nielsutrecht/jwt-angular-spring) you gave.

The example application uses the Jjwt library to create and decrypt the JSON web tokens. In my example application the token is created when a person manages to log in successfully. This happens in the `login()` method in `UserController.java`. A successful login (the example application doesn't deal with silly stuff like passwords for simplicity) returns a `LoginResponse` with this token. The angular application than sets this as a default header that gets sent with every request. You can store this in local storage or a cookie if you don't want to have them log in again after hitting F5. Again; it's an example that keeps stuff as simple as possible; I left these kinds of things out on purpose.

The header gets read by the `JwtFilter` class and stored in the request context. That way any path can access this information without having to decrypt the header itself.

Although everything is explained pretty in-depth in the corresponding [blog post](http://niels.nu/blog/2015/json-web-tokens.html): let me know if there's anything you don't understand.

Comment: Thank you. It's great to share a good knowledge on 'Jot'. I like this approach and I implemented too in my app. Happy learning !!

Answer (score 2):

When you perform login, you send username and password via HTTP post request. Java web service responds with token if credentials are correct. Frontend AngularJS application stores token into a LocalStorage or as a Cookie. Upon each next request you make, token is sent as a value of `Authorization` header. Java web service will intercept requests and check for existence and validity of token.

You can take a look at this [demo application](https://github.com/BranislavLazic/angular-security) I made too.

Comment: Is it created, or it existed before? Try by removing it from LocalStorage or Cookies.

Comment: Thank you. I clear cache and I don't see any token now before login. I will delete EDIT-1 too.

Comment: You're welcome. :) Consider to accept answer if it helped you.

Comment: Yes, will do, but I got last question to ask. It appears that implementation class of GenericFilterBean is getting called many times and also loadByUsername. Do you know why? (Pls update your answer too)  I also create EDIT-1 to show some logs as a proof.

Comment: Not sure to be honest. Seems like everything is fine with application from link you posted. Feel free to rely on code from my demo application.