# How to attach jwt token on every page after successful authentication?

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt

I followed [this](https://github.com/szerhusenBC/jwt-spring-security-demo) code and implemented the jwt authentication successfully. I am using this authentication in my web application. I am able to get the token on the login page. After that how to attach that token to the header of all the subsequent requests.  I stored the token in local storage, but when I navigate to next page after successful login before js loads, the page getting loaded with 401 error.

How should I achieve this?

Comment: plain js only with spring MVC

Comment: this might be helpful.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34551390/how-jwt-actually-works-with-spring-mvc-to-create-token-and-validate-token

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to use token based security with the Web MVC architecture.  I did a quick search for any tutorials on how to do it that way and all I was able to find is examples of REST APIs that use token based security.

The reason is that with Spring MVC, each link you click is going to redirect you to a controller endpoint that is going to render the HTML and send it back to the browser.  Unless you somehow made every link on your site include the token in a header or perhaps used a cookie to store the token, you'll get a 401 error because the token isn't present in the request.

If you were to use Angular JS (or your favorite front end framework) with a REST backend, you'll be able to use the JS to put whatever you need in the header to make sure the user is authenticated and has access to the resource.  There a lot of example projects out there that demonstrate how to do this.

**Disclaimer** I haven't been able to find a reliable source that definitively says that token based security is for REST only.  I'm basing this on experience and readily what I see out there in terms of tutorials and how to articles.

Answer (score 0):

Ich totally agree to the answer from blur0224, you have to set the token in the request header of every link on your pages. I don't know how to achieve this. Furthermore I think that JWT token based authentication is not the right way for MVC based app. I would use it in SPAs build with frameworks like Angularjs.

Why don't you use the 'standard' Spring authentication?